# Hide JsonValue from log file using <flter-spec>

Tags: json, logging, filter, wildfly

I'am trying to hide the Json value of the student field from log files using **filter-spec**,

this is my **filter-spec** :

[image]

after i applied the flter this is how the data is showing in the log file

[image]

all i want it is to replace ("student" : "testStudent") with ("student": "****") instead it is got replaced with ("student: ****)

does anyone have an example on how to hide the json value using filter-spec?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not actually possible replace a JSON value with a filter. You'd need to use a custom filter or custom handler in order to do this.

You could file a [feature request](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/LOGMGR) though. It does seem like a decent idea for a filter to be able to filter values in structured formats.